# Got "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl" error while installing ssl using pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I was installing ssl using pip on my local machine to resolve my ssl certificate validation issues using following command

```
pip install ssl
```

and then , I got these  errors

```
Collecting ssl
  Using cached ssl-1.16.tar.gz (33 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7f7fanj7\\ssl_ad84b70dabca4cdd8020026884a3206a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7f7fanj7\\ssl_ad84b70dabca4cdd8020026884a3206a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) 
else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pq2mx6oj'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7f7fanj7\ssl_ad84b70dabca4cdd8020026884a3206a\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7f7fanj7\ssl_ad84b70dabca4cdd8020026884a3206a\setup.py", line 33
        print 'looking for', f
                          ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/21/f469c9923235f8c36d5fd5334ed11e2681abad7e0032c5aba964dcaf9bbb/ssl-1.16.tar.gz#sha256=ac21156fee6aee9eb8d765bbb16f5f49492d81ff4b22f7b8fc001d2251120930 (from https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached ssl-1.15.tar.gz (32 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7f7fanj7\\ssl_f494dbee500946faa356411d0da468c8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7f7fanj7\\ssl_f494dbee500946faa356411d0da468c8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) 
else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-4_6zjbtg'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7f7fanj7\ssl_f494dbee500946faa356411d0da468c8\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7f7fanj7\ssl_f494dbee500946faa356411d0da468c8\setup.py", line 74
        print 'looking for', f
                          ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/c2/846a19d1572ec6cb8ac438d58a898de8926d32e13f0355cdf4ab00864b5f/ssl-1.15.tar.gz#sha256=1266302ce62c4b60c7ca0e1d3d104ba11d2749e5881d8ac4f006cf9a0446d589 (from https://pypi.org/simple/ssl/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: 1.15, 1.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ssl
```

Comment: Looks like something is messed up with your Python setup or installation. It tries to install a package for Python 2 even though you are using Python 3.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you are right but if you see [docs](https://pypi.org/project/ssl/) i guess it does not support `python 3`

Comment: @BhavyaParikh: Python 3 has a ssl module. I'm not sure why you want to install a really old version suitable only for ancient Python 2 versions.

Comment: So can you add that which command is used to install `ssl` module with `python 3`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thats because when I run my program it raised a requests.exceptions.SSLError so I tried to install it manually with pip to solve that problem , but  then the errors that i have mentioned appeared

Comment: And what __exactly__ did this `requests.exceptions.SSLError` say?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 706, 
in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382,

Comment: @SteffenUllrich in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 421, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 429, in ssl_wrap_socket

Comment: @SteffenUllrich   sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()

Comment: @SteffenUllrich   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer 
certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, 
in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:

Comment: @SteffenUllrich HTTPSConnectionPool(host='praktikum.gunadarma.ac.id', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/index.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging-into-websites.py", line 13, in <module>
    site = s.get(url,headers=headers,timeout=5)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages

Comment: @SteffenUllrich \requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='praktikum.gunadarma.ac.id', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/index.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

Comment: @MedianoSandie: the output clearly shows that the problem is not a missing ssl module (i.e. `pip install ssl` is not needed at all) but that the certificate cannot be verified *"certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate"*. There are  zillions of questions exactly about this problem on this site, so please look at these. If you don't find a useful answer ask a new question with enough details for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a missing understanding: the problem of a failed certificate validation in the ssl module cannot be solved by installing the ssl module (which is already installed). Thus the question is going in the completely wrong direction when trying to solve the original problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've solved the issue I mentioned above by adding extra param on Session.get method which is verify=False , but then i got "InsecureRequestWarning Unverified HTTPS request is being made" warning . Is it okay to ignore this warning? will this be harmful or something?

Comment: @MedianoSandie: *" Is it okay to ignore this warning? will this be harmful or something?"* - for testing yes, for production usually not since you basically loose the protection offered by using HTTPS instead of HTTP. But this topic is actually outside of your original question. So if you need to continue with this please ask a new question instead.